# How to set an InputType to display negative float number for an inputTypeEditText

Tags: android, android-inputtype, android-textinputedittext

I need to display negative and positive values inside an **TextInputEditText**. I am setting the **inputType** programatically:

```
inputTypeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

the above code works for positive float numbers only.

And also I tried

```
inputTypeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

but this keyboard is similar with the text keyboard and shows to much characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the float keyboard which displays float positive and negative numbers using the following code:

```
inputTypeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED|
           InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```